# Data does not get written to tickerplant unless I stop the Java process

Tags: java, kdb

I'm trying to write some data to tickerplant using the code below:

```
connection.ks(new Object[]{".u.upd", table, data});
LOG.info("Cycle {} for {} table completed", counter, table);
counter++;
```

I can see the log output, but when I check the database table the data is not there. If I kill the java process, the data in the last "cycle" will be inserted.

If I use the method .k instead of .ks it will just block.

Comment: Did you resolve this at all as I have similiar issue?

Comment: Yes. Everything worked (without any code change) after a full restart of KDB and all other components connected to it. I have no idea why it didn't work before and I'm afraid this might happen again. Please let me know if you solve this somehow/find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these [kdb/java examples](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-java-api) will help.

Else I advise posting your entire code.